# Boost hana find type in set

Tags: c++, boost-hana

New to `boost::hana` and trying a simple experiment to find a type in a set of types and just print its `typeid.name`. However I am getting static_assert errors (NOTE: Xcode 7.2.1)

This is the code:

```
auto set = hana::make_set(hana::type_c<int>, hana::type_c<float>);

auto s = hana::adjust( set, hana::type_c<int>, [](auto x){ std::cout << typeid(x).name() << std::endl; });
```

The error is:

> "hana::adjust(xs, value, f) requires 'xs' to be a Functor");

However this seems at odds with the documentation for adjust which states that `xs` needs to be a structure.

Any advice appreciated as I assume I'm missing something fundamental in my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Hana uses functional programming terminology, where **Functor** means something different from what it typically is used to mean in C++ (i.e. a function object).

In the signature for `adjust`:

```
(auto&& xs, auto&& value, auto&& f)
```

> adjust: F(T) × U × (T → T) → F(T)

then `xs` is F(T), a **Functor** over **T**; `f` is (T → T), a function object that maps values of **T** to **T**.

The other problem here is that lowercase and uppercase F refer to different objects within the signature.

**Set** is not a **Functor**, because of its invariant that values occur at most once. If you replace `make_set` with `make_tuple` (and ensure that your `f` returns a value), your code will compile ([Example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Bu4jhZH3MZekNiXw)):

```
auto t = hana::make_tuple(hana::type_c<int>, hana::type_c<float>);
hana::adjust(t, hana::type_c<int>, [](auto x){ std::cout << typeid(x).name() << std::endl; return x; });
```

However, you should probably not be using `hana::adjust` here, as you don't care about the return value; instead, use `hana::filter` with `hana::for_each` ([Example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fK0Hg7OwRYJ8p0O5)):

```
auto s = hana::make_set(hana::type_c<int>, hana::type_c<float>);
hana::for_each(hana::filter(hana::to_tuple(s), hana::equal.to(hana::type_c<int>)),
               [](auto x){ std::cout << typeid(x).name() << std::endl; });
```

Comment: Many thanks; I certainly have a lot to learn about functional and meta programming at this level. 

As an aside, does haha provide a way to take a collection of types and execute a function based on one of them matching without having to search linearly through a list. i.e. Perform a lookup table like call?

Comment: @AKB you probably want `hana::contains` (which returns `hana::true_` or `hana::false_`), or `hana::find` (which returns `hana::just<...>` or `hana::nothing`). Both of these work efficiently on `hana::set`.